# Python dowloading data and "post" url after cURL is returning 400 error

Tags: python, python-requests

New to Python
trying to extract the shorted time series on a stock (PLS) here:
https://www.halo-technologies.com/markets/shares/asx/PLS

Here is the code, and as you can see the url is POST and not get, how can this be changed to a get request so as to work or is there another solution.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

headers = {
    'authority': 'api.halotechnologies.com.au',
    'accept': '*/*',
    'accept-language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'origin': 'https://www.halo-technologies.com',
    'referer': 'https://www.halo-technologies.com/markets/shares/asx/PLS',
    'sec-ch-ua': '^\\^Google',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '^\\^Windows^\\^',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'cross-site',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like      Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'x-halo-signature':  't=1701286548,s=88776bd956b7658b3c993f6e6b2ae668400d3c7ff9ca4c6cf8d3f8773ed1581b',
}

data =  '^{^\\^countryCode^\\^:^\\^AU^\\^,^\\^security^\\^:^\\^PLS^\\^,^\\^components^\\^:^\\^shortSell^\\^^}'

response = requests.post('https://api.halotechnologies.com.au/api/security/quote/public',    headers=headers, data=data)

print(response)
```

I was expecting to see the data from the page as per this screen after inspect etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests

api_url = "https://api.halotechnologies.com.au/api/security/quote/public"
payload = {"components": "shortSell", "countryCode": "AU", "security": "PLS"}

data = requests.post(api_url, json=payload).json()

df = pd.DataFrame(data["data"]["shortSell"])
print(df.head())
```

Prints:

```
     asAtDate     price  shortSold
0  2007-09-19  0.791827        NaN
1  2007-09-20  0.628804        NaN
2  2007-09-21  0.698671        NaN
3  2007-09-24  0.605515        NaN
4  2007-09-25  0.582226        NaN
```

Comment: thanks for the response Andrej, What would be required to also download the share price? This is the other series on the graph.

Comment: @KRT The column `price` is the price value and the column `shortSold` is the shortSell price on that graph

Comment: thanks Again Andrej, If I want the stock price history I need to use payload = {"components": "brush", "countryCode": "AU", "security": "PLS"}